# javafx, tooltip: how to set font color

Tags: javafx

How can I set the font color in a Tooltip class? With yellow background the Message remains white.

```
final Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
tooltip.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
tooltip.setText("Message");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-fx-text-fill` for the text color.

E.g. if you want red text on yellow background:

```
tooltip.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow; -fx-text-fill: red;");
```

Comment: Wroks! Thx, was always looking for "text-color" or similar.